# Get categories, cache problem with getStoreCategories

Tags: category, ce-1.9.0.1, query

I have two different template blocks (extends Mage_Core_Block_Template). Both query some categories.

First:

```
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    $children = $_helper->getStoreCategories(false, true, false)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('product_slider')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_slider', array('neq' => ''))
        ->addOrderField('product_slider')
        ->addOrderField('name');
```

Second:

```
    $children = $_helper->getStoreCategories(false, true, false)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('themen_teaser')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('themen_teaser', array('neq' => ''))
        ->addOrderField('themen_teaser')
        ->addOrderField('name');
```

Problem is that first query is cached and second query returns the same values. You can see the caching in [getStoreCategories()](http://doc-magento.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php.source.html#l54).

How do I get those categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah got it. Use

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->...
```

Instead of

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$children = $_helper->getStoreCategories(false, true, false)
->...
```